# Why didn't the villain repair his own injuries?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-3

At the end of *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3*, we see that the villain still has the injuries inflicted on them (presumably) many years prior.

Given all of the wealth and technology at their disposal, why did they never heal themselves? It seems to be something easier than most of what they have done already in the movie.

Comment: Obviously, if they could, they would have. So clearly they couldn't.

Comment: @Paulie_D - There are many things I *could* do. The fact that I haven't doesn't mean that I can't. And the question why I haven't (yet) is pretty legit

Comment: The villain didn't seem to even attempt to do things that we can do today, despite possessing the technology to create living planets.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I'm wondering if this is an easter egg, or a callback to the comics. They did very much resemble another Marvel villain during the reveal. It may have some relevance to the story that I'm not aware of.

Comment: So either he could not do it or he could but didn't want to. Either way you have your answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D, the question wasn't what did\didn't he do it was why.

Comment: I think it's a plot hole and artistic mistake. Only reason for him to not fix it would be to remember, fixating on his defeat. He could do something like that but not as far as his body was concerned.

Answer (score 2):

The same question could be asked of Nebula, once she was freed of Thanos influence, as all those cybernetics implant were a reminder of Thanos influence and torture.

So we can assume that 'magical regrowth' does not exists **in the MCU**, at least not to a level that would make keeping cybernetic/mechanical prostheses redundant.

Next, from what I understand, the High Evolutionary seeks perfection in all things. And as a strong narcissist, he extend this perfection to his body and competences.

Not only is nobody else but him "good enough" to operate on him (which makes working on your face a tad complicated), but no other material than his **own original body** is good enough.

Comment: Is this supported by any in universe dialog in the movie, or other canonical media, or covered in scripts or source mmterial.